# Making bluetooth stereo audio work in PC games when it is silent

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, gaming

I have some bluetooth headphones and a windows 10 pc. the bluetooth stereo audio source doesnt work in games (i.e. modern warfare 2019). However the 'hands-free ag audio' does and it automatically toggles when the game is started. when I switch to stereo, which is the higher quality audio, everything is silent. How do you get the bluetooth stereo to work in a game?

[image]

UPDATE: 
added screenshots from sound settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share a screenshot of your Sound settings > playback, which is set for default speakers? and which for default communication device?

Comment: see screenshots

Comment: Everything seems normal. Perform the following tests: 
1. Play a music file. set output to stereo headphones. do you hear it clearly? 
2. Set Sound output to stereo headphones (before launching game), test music, stop if it works, then start the game and see?
3. Try setting the stereo headphones as both default devices. 
4. Worst case: uninstall drivers and reinstall.
Which game are you trying in? Try some other games? Try browser games. Maybe check the sound settings of the game in question

Answer (score 0):

go into settings and click on privacy then click on microphone and where it says microphone access for this device, if its on turn it off and it should fix the problem as I had the same trouble with my computer when playing games and when I turned that off I could have both music and the in game sound working together on my computer hope this helps
bluetooth

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).